# How did the rightful heir know about Worf's vision?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

About fifteen minutes into [6x23 Rightful Heir](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rightful_Heir_%28episode%29), Kahless reminds Worf of a vision Worf had when he was young. But later on it is revealed that

> Kahless is actually a clone with imprinted memories from the scriptures, which certainly don't include a vision had by a back then pretty unknown young Klingon.

So how does he know? Or, since Worf doesn't seem to remember, did Kahless make it up? But that would not be honorable, something a Kahless certainly wouldn't consider.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seeming plot-hole is actually explained in [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/249.txt). Worf told Torin (the priest) about his vision as a boy and this memory was implanted into the Kahless clone:

> **KAHLESS :** *So I did not do any of the things I remember... I was never at the city of Quin'lat... I never went to the Kri'stat
>   Volcano...* (beat) *But what about Worf?* ***I remember appearing to
>   him in the caves of No'Mat when he was a boy...***
>
> **TORIN : *We gave you that memory as well. Worf told me of his vision when he first arrived on Boreth.***

In the episode itself, this piece of dialogue was removed.

Comment: Weird, I watched this episode just this morning and cannot remember that, and the more I read from that script the more I suspect it is not accurate - I also don't remember Worf actually saying that his extraordinary achievement were joining Starfleet. Then again, it _was_ 6 in the morning...

Comment: @Zommuter - You're absolutely right. It skips straight over this piece of dialogue to the next line down.

Comment: I also just rewatched it. So is that script authentic and the scene was merely shortened? In that case your answer is correct nonetheless

Comment: @zommuter - The script is the *original* show script, as written. The scripts on that site are considered to be fully canon, unless directly contradicted by the TV show.

Comment: In that case the script conveys the intention but the scene was probably shortened afterwards. Well, I guess it does make sense Worf told Torin about his vision, who did then logically add it to Kahless' memory

Comment: @Zommuter - Incidental dialogue often gets trimmed out. In the "Captain's Log" interviews for this episode, MIchael Dorn remarks that there were only two very minor script changes, both to cut down the running time. Apparently the "temple" scene was a nightmare due to the fog. It ended up taking three days to film what should have been a one day shoot.

Comment: It also makes sense given that Worf was an integral part of the "con". The priests' entire plan revolved around making Worf a believer, so that he would then champion Kahless' return to others.

Answer (score 5):

## This is weeks, not minutes, into his visit

Worf had spent a great deal of time seeking a vision at the monetary.  Surly, when on a quest for a vision, the querent would tell the cleric of past visions.  The implication in the show is that he told *someone* about the vision, and that memory was implanted into the clone.  This is also the only way this makes sense.

The reaction of Worf in the scene in question is a face of realization.  Worf does not need to be reminded of the vision.  Worf speaks no words at the 00:16:00 mark, which is the face that is the root of this question.  Logically it cannot be a face of remembrance, but of astonishment.

Comment: What I meant was in said episode around 0:15:00. I somehow doubt _all_ visions of Kahless ever had by every Klingon in existence were recorded

Comment: How so if Kahless has to _remind_ Worf of the vision that he apparently has forgotten since? Yet Worf does not deny it

Comment: I'll have to review that scene, but I thought Kahless said something like "We have met before - you may not remember it, but you had a vision of me when you were young". To me, Worf's reaction didn't seem astonishment at him knowing (which would make no sense if he recently told someone about it, since that person could easily have told the clone without memory imprinting) but rather the memory of that vision surfacing from deep down

Comment: you're right, I rewatched that scene, your answer also makes perfectly sense. I accepted Richard's answer though, since at least in the script Torin explicitly admits to this. though that makes me wonder why Kahless didn't worry about probably only remember the visions of recent visitors, or whether his head was truly filled with all visions ever reported...

Answer (score 3):

The programmed memories included also personal information from the priests and not only the sacred texts:

> All of his memories were actually programmed in from the sacred texts or from personal information the priests had. [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rightful_Heir_%28episode%29)

Thus it is not unfeasible to include details on Worf in the programmed memories as he is not anymore a "pretty unknown young Klingon". The Vision will most likely have been recorded when he talked to priests about it back when he had the vision.

Comment: This sounds rather speculative - that would basically imply every vision ever had by a Klingon in those hundreds of years since Kahless left was imprinted, and that the clone could cope with bearing the memory of so many encounters. Even if only the visions of the last, say ten years were included I'm not sure that wouldn't be too many

Comment: Worf is rather important in the federation and also well known in the Empire. I would assume that the clone should indeed be fed with such information about the most important people to appear credible.

Comment: with the script in Richard's answer that makes indeed sense. The show did unfortunately cut that subtle aspect